# Java AbstractProcessor fetch Project Name and source file path/ name information

Tags: java

I have a custom annotation in a file called "TestAnnotation.java" inside Java Project named ("SampleProject")  like below.

```
public class TestAnnotation {
   @customelement(folder = "/path/")
   public testMethod() {

   }
}
```

How I can extract the project Name i.e. "SampleProject" and file path/name for TestAnnotation.java, using AbstractProcessor, below?

```
public class CompileTimeAnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, 
                           RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {

        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By creating a file using processEnv.getFiler() and call getURI(), Project name using path segments.